# Migration fails with "missing migrations" errors

Tags: migrations, 9

I am trying to migrate a Drupal 7 site to Drupal 9 using the Migrate module user interface. I have read through and followed the corresponding tutorials on drupal.org, but the migration still fails.

Given that my original Drupal 7 site is quite complex, for testing purposes, I created a fresh installation of Drupal 7 and created some dummy nodes; then I ran the upgrade from the user interface in Drupal 9.

The *What will be upgraded?* page indicated that 29 modules would be upgraded (including the Node module). After performing the upgrade, I got the following messages:

> Completed 39 upgrade tasks successfully
> 40 upgrades failed
> Upgrade process not completed

The content hasn't been migrated.

When I checked the upgrade log, I found the following error:

> Migration d7_node:article did not meet the requirements. Missing migrations d7_node_type, d7_user. requirements: d7_node_type. requirements: d7_user.

The *d7_node_type.yml* and *d7_user.yml* migration files are there in the appropriate Drupal 9 folders, so I don't understand what the problem is. What am I missing?

Comment: Follow-up: I've run the above migration test both from Drupal 7 to 9, and from Drupal 7 to 8, on two different servers (my web hosting provider's and a XAMPP local server) with the same results. Clearly, I must be missing something. Could someone point me in the right direction to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same messages in my log when I first tried a migration using the user interface. I also had the following which once sorted out appeared to clear up the other errors.

> General error: 1267 Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_general_ci,IMPLICIT) >and (utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,IMPLICIT)

It seems the collations of the databases need to be the same. My source db from my drupal 7 site is utf8mb4_general_ci and the default for my new db is utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci.
So I used phpmyadmin to 'convert' the drupal 7 db to utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci which did the trick.

I'm no mysql expert, as demonstrated by my use or phpmyadmin instead of the command line, so you should use a copy of your source db at the very least.